# How to show letter one by one in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I Want A Batch File To Make Show Letters In A Word One By One

Example:

```
a
ab
abc
```

I Tried This but, I don't really want to keep copying and pasting like this:

```
cls
echo.
echo  a
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo  ab
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
cls
echo.
echo  abc
ping localhost -n 1 >nul
```

It resulted a messy and a long code.

Comment: If you mean type like a Typewriter effect, Take look at [TypeWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Typewriter+batch)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for a loop. You can later add a timer, to make it look more like a typewrite effect.

```
enter @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "alphabet=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

 for /L %%i in (0,1,25) do (
  set "output="
   for /L %%j in (0,1,%%i) do (
    set "output=!output!!alphabet:~%%j,1!"
 )
 echo !output!
 ping localhost -n 1 >nul
 cls
)

pause
endlocal
```